# login via twitter ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want the user to have the ability to login via Twitter instead of filling the form of sign up, however when the user hit on "Login via Twitter " I want to retrieve the basic information I need from Twitter API.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: wat u mean wats the question

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot write the code for you.

Comment: i had mention that i want to login via twitter in my app

Comment: i also know dat u ll not write the code for me

Comment: well its ok will  campbell

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default social framework,

- Add social frame work to your project.
- Then add header `Accounts/Accounts.h` & `Social/Social.h` header to your code file.
- Then after add below method & call it when required.

Code :

```
    - (void) getInfo
    {
        ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if (granted) {

            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account

            if (accounts.count > 0)
            {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

                // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter

                SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
                [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                // Making the request

                [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        // Check if we reached the reate limit

                        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                            NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                            return;
                        }

                        // Check if there was an error

                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                            return;
                        }

                        // Check if there is some response data

                        if (responseData) {

                            NSError *error = nil;
                            NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                            // Filter the preferred data

                            NSString *screen_name = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
                            NSString *name = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"name"];

                            int followers = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"followers_count"] integerValue];
                            int following = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"friends_count"] integerValue];
                            int tweets = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"statuses_count"] integerValue];

                            NSString *profileImageStringURL = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"];
                            NSString *bannerImageStringURL =[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"profile_banner_url"];


                            // Update the interface with the loaded data

                            nameLabel.text = name;
                            usernameLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",screen_name];

                            tweetsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tweets];
                            followingLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", following];
                            followersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", followers];

                            NSString *lastTweet = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"status"] objectForKey:@"text"];
                            lastTweetTextView.text= lastTweet;



                            // Get the profile image in the original resolution

                            profileImageStringURL = [profileImageStringURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_normal" withString:@""];
                            [self getProfileImageForURLString:profileImageStringURL];


                            // Get the banner image, if the user has one

                            if (bannerImageStringURL) {
                                NSString *bannerURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mobile_retina", bannerImageStringURL];
                                [self getBannerImageForURLString:bannerURLString];
                            } else {
                                bannerImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor underPageBackgroundColor];
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No access granted");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: actually i want to login via twitter. r u getting me??

Comment: this code directly get the info of perticular username

Comment: Yes, Its because you already have added your twitter credential in your twitter setting app..

Comment: Did you get the alert for permission? And If you haven't added any account then you will get alert message to login into that application. Let me know if you need anymore clarification

Comment: yes i got the alert but i want to redirect it to the signit url of twitter

Comment: Man social framework provide deep integration of Twitter. So it takes required data from system itself & then doing necessary operation. If OS provide such nice facility then why you would like to re-direct user to Sign In Page? Any specific need?

Comment: its the silly task so i have to do it brother. i did it with STTwiter. and thank u very much for ur help

Comment: i m freshers so i cant but u can upmark my question so dat i get more reputation

Answer (score 1):

You can get demo code

```
https://github.com/nst/STTwitter
```

If you are using pod then use write "STTwitter" in pod file and update you pod.

Answer (score 0):

While I won't write the code for you, you can embark on your journey here:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

Twitter provides a step-by-step way of using its API. If you have any problems with that, then you can feel free to ask us here.

Comment: Yeah and if you need any other of its API, it's all here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation